# Play framework application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework, openshift

I'm am trying to deploy a PlayFramework application on OpenShift using this cartridge : https://github.com/tyrcho/openshift-cartridge-play2

But when I start the gear I get this error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[ @ file:/var/lib/openshift/573efff0e299d9096f000bd0/app-root/data/deploy/junk-1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/: 2: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'logback.xml' (if you intended 'logback.xml' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:101)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.readServerConfigSettings(ProdServerStart.scala:76)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:37)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse:  @ file:/var/lib/openshift/573efff0e299d9096f000bd0/app-root/data/deploy/junk-1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/: 2: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'logback.xml' (if you intended 'logback.xml' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser$ParseContext.parseError(ConfigDocumentParser.java:201)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser$ParseContext.parseError(ConfigDocumentParser.java:197)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser$ParseContext.parseObject(ConfigDocumentParser.java:408)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser$ParseContext.parse(ConfigDocumentParser.java:595)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigDocumentParser.parse(ConfigDocumentParser.java:14)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:260)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:248)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:180)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:174)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:307)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:747)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:710)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:180)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:174)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:299)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseResources(ConfigFactory.java:1002)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseResources(ConfigFactory.java:930)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseResources(ConfigFactory.java:944)
    at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$1.apply(Configuration.scala:66)
    at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$1.apply(Configuration.scala:66)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:66)
    ... 4 more
```

This even occurs when I use the default activator template (activator new my-appliaction play-scala).

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you use the correct version of the openshift-cartridge-play2? The current one is for Play 2.5. Which version is your Play?

Comment: Yes, the version i am using is 2.5.3.

Comment: `Configuration error: Configuration error[ @ file:/var/lib/openshift/573efff0e299d9096f000bd0/app-root/data/deploy/junk-1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/: 2: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'logback.xml' (if you intended 'logback.xml' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)]`

The error is self describing, change `'logback.xml'` to `"logback.xml"`

Comment: @EdoPut Yes, that is the error but, I don't understand why the error occurs. It seems to be loopuing through the file names in the configuration folder  (/conf) and not liking the strcture. Even though that they are the default file names.

Comment: This question isn't much use without adding an example of what your config looks like